# Moved CPanel account and now can't access database

Tags: php, authentication

I've just migrated a site across to a new account on CPanel and I just can't access the databases at all. The error I'm receiving is:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
```

I've changed the usernames and passwords in the config and connection files, and altered paths, but it's left me stumped.

Comment: I can't check the password, as it's SALT protected. I'm not too hot on this - does anyone know how to check salty passwords in the db?

Answer (score 0):

OK, panic over. The server people just responded with a "You should able to access the database now. Please let me know if you need any further assistance."

Frustrating, but happily sorted!